# Passing the function as an argument in higher order function is giving error

Tags: javascript, arguments, higher-order-functions

Uncaught TypeError: firstUpper is not a function at transformer

If I reverse the order of the arguments in transformer function then the code runs fine. But why is it happening in this way? The order of arguments should not matter here i think.

```
function firstUpperCaseWord(st){
let st1 = st.split(" ");

st1[0] = st1[0].toUpperCase();

st=st1.join(" ");

return st;
}


function transformer(string, firstUpper){

console.log(firstUpper(string));

}

transformer(firstUpperCaseWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `transformer` functions needs two arguments to work, and you are passing only one - you forgot to pass in the string.

You have `transformer(firstUpperCaseWord);`, and you want `transformer('foo bar biz', firstUpperCaseWord);`